# All exception breakpoint can't catch objc_exception_throw

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, exception

I recently get a strange problem, exception breakpoint can't catch objc_exception_throw. In this case, I can't locate where is the problem? Follow is stack strace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #7: tid = 0x40df6f, 0x00000001097a9b8a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, name = 'com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader', stop reason = breakpoint 1.3 2.2
  * frame #0: 0x00000001097a9b8a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x0000000109b749ad CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    frame #2: 0x00000001091abab7 Foundation`NSRequestConcreteImplementation + 240
    frame #3: 0x00000001091b2da2 Foundation`-[NSStream(NSStream) streamStatus] + 39
    frame #4: 0x0000000107ab011d CFNetwork`HTTPProtocol::useNetStreamInfoForRequest(MetaNetStreamInfo*, HTTPRequestMessage const*, unsigned char) + 311
    frame #5: 0x0000000107abc561 CFNetwork`HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::dispatchConnectionToProtocol(HTTPNetConnection*, HTTPConnectionCacheEnqueuedRequestInfo*, unsigned char) + 265
    frame #6: 0x0000000107abb67a CFNetwork`HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::ingestTube(Tube*) + 728
    frame #7: 0x0000000107abf0d1 CFNetwork`___ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry12newTubeReadyEP4TubeP9__CFError_block_invoke + 26
    frame #8: 0x00000001079f7d16 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 72
    frame #9: 0x0000000109a7cb44 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    frame #10: 0x00000001079f7bd7 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 133
    frame #11: 0x00000001079f7a16 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::perform() + 256
    frame #12: 0x00000001079f782c CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 72
    frame #13: 0x0000000109aa9c91 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #14: 0x0000000109a9fb5d CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    frame #15: 0x0000000109a9f194 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 868
    frame #16: 0x0000000109a9ebc6 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #17: 0x0000000107a7d250 CFNetwork`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
    frame #18: 0x00000001091201dd Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1194
    frame #19: 0x000000010a874268 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #20: 0x000000010a8741e5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #21: 0x000000010a87241d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
```

Any suggestion will be appreciation!

Comment: Looks like `[NSStream streamStatus]`.  There should be some text associated with the exception which will give you many clues as to the issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe The problem is Xcode does show text associated with the exception and exception breakpoint can't catch this exception.

Comment: Objective-C exceptions should probably be considered fatal anyway, so that should not matter.